# Why can't I manage my server using MySQL Worckbench (WMI Status...)

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to manage my MySQL Server using Workbench 5.2.31 CE Rev 7115 with MySQL 5.5.8 on Windows Server 2003, but I'm getting this error:

```
RuntimeError: Could not initialize WMI interface: Workbench.wmiOpenSession(); Internal error: Instantion of IWbemLocatio failed.

Internal Error: WMI status code text creation failed
```

I can use [SQL Development], [Data Modeling], but not [Server Administration]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with that tool, but if it's a WMI problem, you might want to make sure WMI is enabled in Windows Server and that any firewall ports are open that are used by WMI.

Maybe [this](http://www.poweradmin.com/help/enableWMI.aspx) will help, or Google for "enable wmi in windows 2003" for other possibly relevant information.

Comment: I never heard about WMI until now, jejjejje... Thank you... I had problemas with that, searching in google found this [WMI Troubleshooting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394603.aspx) very useful... and this [post](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/re-install-wmi-windows-xp-t531758.html)

Comment: WMI is basically the Microsoft bastardization of SNMP.  If that helps; if you know what SNMP is.